# How to filter rows and columns based on the maximum value in a Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Shown below are few details on a DataFrame.

[image]

Below is the syntax that is been used and do not get the expected output.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['country','Year','Value'], ascending=[True,True,False])
df = df.drop_duplicates('country')
```

how could I get the expected output shown below

[image]

Comment: What is the output you currently get? Where is your exact problem?

Comment: Did you check for the extra arguments do `drop_duplicates`?

Comment: If you're after the highest value per country, then sorting on year is irrelevant, and you should remove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try sorting by "Value" and keeping the last row for each country

```
>>> df.sort_values("Value").drop_duplicates("country",keep="last")
    Year country  Value
2   2003     USA   7000
6   2002   India   9000
10  2001   Japan  10000
```

Alternatively, you could use `groupby`:

```
>>> df[df["Value"].eq(df.groupby("country")["Value"].transform('max'))]
    Year country  Value
2   2003     USA   7000
6   2002   India   9000
10  2001   Japan  10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.sort_values('Value',ascending=False).groupby('country').head(1)
```